# Is there a way to change the reflection of an object to look inverted in a mirror surface? So that text reads normally, for instance

Tags: materials, lighting, mirror

I am trying to make sure I can read the text in a reflection during render. I am not sure how I should go about doing this. Edit: I should state that I need both the object projecting the light onto the mirror to read forwards, as well as the reflection.

Comment: If the text and the mirror are both facing the camera, then the backside of the text should be what's reflected, which should read the right way.  If I'm thinking correctly...

Comment: But if you needed a fix, you're in render layer territory, I think

Comment: Could you illustrate with a picture of the 'wrong' version?